# Maximum Likelihood Estimation and Standard Errors

Tags: maximum-likelihood, standard-error

Suppose, I have the following model:

$$
Y = X^T\beta + u_t
$$

where

$u_t \sim\operatorname{GARCH}(1,1)$ with Gaussian mixture as error distribution (or even something more weird, like normal-inverse-Gaussian and inverse-Gaussian mixture).

That is, I have plenty of parameters to be estimated. ML works fine but is there a way for easy parameters standard errors computation without deriving information matrix?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can always numerically approximate the information matrix (i.e the negative hessian matrix of your log likilhood function evaluated at the max. see https://files.nyu.edu/mrg217/public/mle_introduction1.pdf).  Another option would be to bootstrap the MLE routine.  Both these would work fine, the former is less computationally expensive (especially with a lot of parameters).

If you are using a numerical optimization routine, there are often options for returning a numeric approximate to the hessian evaluated at the min/max.  I don't know what software your using .  In R, the function optim is great for this.  The package numericDeriv includes a hessian function that will do this approximation for you as well.